# How to rotate a dial image on its postion.

Tags: android

I have a wheel, I want to rotate it on its position. my code is rotating this image but its going to change its position. i want to keep this image on fix place.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inner_dial);

    float rotation = (float) Math.toDegrees(90);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotation);

    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.inner_temp);

    dialImage.setBackgroundResource(0);

    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),
            bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    dialImage.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);

}
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:background="@drawable/inner_temp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/inner_dial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this `rotate.xml` in the `anim` folder in `res`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

Start your animation:

```
dialImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.rotate ) );
```

**EDIT:**

To use rotate animation prgrammatically:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, pivotXType, pivotXValue, pivotYType, pivotYValue);
dialImage.startAnimation(anim);
```

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#RotateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29) for detailed description.

Comment: thanks @Vineet,,, but my degree value is going to be changed so i can't use rotate.xml

Comment: I could not get what do you mean by my degree value is going to be changed, if you don't want to use rotating angle to be 360 then change it or if your angle will change in future then you can use programmatically.

Comment: Yaa @Vineet my angle is going to change  .. so i am rotating image pragmatically.. but on diffrent-2 angle image is moving on its original place.

Comment: plz check the edit section and pass your changed angle every time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the reference point of the coordinate system. What happens is, that your image gets rotated 90 degrees around this reference point. In order to rotate the image in place you need to transform your image position in a way, that the center of the image and the coordinate systems's reference point are identical.